# How to style Flowbite React Components

Tags: reactjs, flowbite

Is there a way to style Flowbite react components? Like, how do i make the navbar transparent.

`<Navbar fluid={true} rounded={true}></Navbar>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style the Navbar and other Flowbite React components using the `className` prop.

For example, to make the navbar transparent, you can use the following TailwindCSS:

```
<Navbar fluid={true} rounded={true} className="bg-transparent"></Navbar>
```

See Navbar Source: https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite-react/blob/cdea61e56e89ee023e8a5daa4c1743692b8a3899/src/lib/components/Navbar/index.tsx#L18

TailwindCSS Background Color Docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color

**NOTE** This is assuming you have setup TailwindCSS with Flowbite according this doc: https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/react/

Comment: Why my TailwindCSS does not work when I tried to set the bg-black alongside with Flowbite React?

Comment: It did not worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, but this ain't true. Looking the typescript definitions you can see that the flowbite-react class specifically omits the className prop inside the NavBar component.

Comment: @Flov Updated the answer, the code I originally linked to did in fact have `className` as an allowed prop... Not sure what happened after this answer though...

Answer (score 3):

I've had this issue before. The issue here is that NavBar itself does not accept a className prop. You can see this inside the typescript definition here: `Omit<PropsWithChildren<ComponentProps<'nav'>>, 'className'>` unless... wait... I just tried to find this piece of code in github and it was gone and className actually **is** accepted in the ts docs. As it turned out flowbite-react was just upgraded ***7 days ago*** to v0.3:

https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite-react/commit/a7f839cc88e5c0beb1456d88f67b12d0b1b781cc

with the following commit message: enable classNames on components

All you have to do is upgrade the flowbite-react package

Answer (score 2):

Try using `class` instead of `className`. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Flowbite React Documentation : https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/customize/theme

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).